# Create multi-photo post on Facebook page using Graph API 7.0 or newer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking for a way to create a multi-photo story on a Page feed. Before Aug 3, it was possible to create an album using `POST /page-id/albums` endpoint. I would then upload multiple photos to the album using `POST /album-id/photos` and Facebook would automatically show a story on the page feed about the new album with pictures in it. This functionality has now been deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version7.0#pages.

Given the deprecation above, is it still possible to create a multi-photo story on a page feed? If yes, please provide the specific endpoints and request structure to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to create a new album via Graph API as of v7.0+. What can be done instead, is to upload multiple pictures to the page in unpublished state using `POST /page-id/photos` and then creating a feed story with the unpublished pictures as attachments, using `POST /page-id/feed`. This workflow, with examples, is explained in detail here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads/